# InputBuilder's PartialView("My") doesn't work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvccontrib, input-builders

my viewmodel

```
public class CaseCreateInput
    {

        [PartialView("My")]
        public object AreaId { get; set; }
}
```

My.aspx partialview

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="Field.Master" 
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<PropertyViewModel<object>>" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="MvcContrib.UI.InputBuilder.Views"%>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="Label" runat="server"><label for="<%=Model.Name%>"><%=Model.Label%></label></asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="Input" runat="server">
<%=Html.DropDownList(Model.Name,Model.Value as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)%></asp:Content>
```

and when I do

`Html.Input(o => o.AreaId)` it's actually looking for the Guid.aspx instead of looking for My.aspx from \views\shared

Comment: Did you try asking Eric Hexter directly? There aren't too many Input builders users on SO...

Comment: I created an issue on codeplex, no response yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched to mvc 2 **Templated Helpers**, now it works

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be coming from the fact that the AreaId property is of type `object`. For example if you change it to `string` it works fine.

Comment: yes I noticed that, in the previous versions of inputbuilders this was working fine, but now it isn't

Comment: @Omu, I've performed my tests with the latest build of `MvcContrib` and it worked for me.

Comment: I'meant for the properties of type object

Comment: Right, I didn't get it :-) Now the logical question that comes is do you really need weakly typed properties in your view models?

Comment: yes, I'm doing this for a long time and it's working perfectly, I use it for lookups because I put in my viewmodel a value of type IEnumerable<SelectListItem> and I receive a string[] containing the selected value(s)

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the file **My** must be *.ascx* and not *.aspx*. It doesn't?

Comment: No, it actually has a masterpage and content placeholders so it's not ascx